# Moodle integration with Google+

Tags: php, google-plus, moodle

I am new to Moodle and I need to integrate a button/link to the main navigation menu so that the logged user can see his/her Google+ Profile. How would you suggest me to do so? Do I have to add an option via some admin, or directly inside the Moodle code?

Comment: Are you wanting to pull that profile into Moodle or are you just wanting to add a link to the navbar?

Comment: I want to put that profile inside an iFrame or something. I've already created a block to display a link, but still don't know how to display that inside an iFrame in Moodle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You plugin belongs in /local/myplugin and needs to have a file called lib.php containing this:

```
function myplugin_extends_navigation(global_navigation $navigation) {
    $nodecoursework->add('Google+',
                         new moodle_url('/local/ocm/view.php?type=2.1'),
                         navigation_node::TYPE_CUSTOM,
                         'Google plus profile',
                         'Google plus');
}
```

Which will automatically add a link to the main navigation once your plugin installs. See here for more [info](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Local_plugins) about making local plugins, also the docs for the add() function.